# Nginx isn't executing php files, while using H5AI

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, php7

I'm trying to install H5AI on my Debian 8 server, I'm using NGINX and PHP7, when I'm trying to access to my adress (in this case share.chaton-poulpe-pieuvre.tk), it makes me download the file, it isn't executing it..

My H5AI files are on /usr/share/nginx/share, in this directory, there is the public and the private directory of H5AI. That's the 0.29.0 of H5AI.

Here is my nginx .conf file for H5AI :

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  share.chaton-poulpe-pieuvre.tk;
        return 301 https://share.chaton-poulpe-pieuvre.tk$request_uri;
}
server {
        server_name  share.chaton-poulpe-pieuvre.tk;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        root /usr/share/nginx/share;
        index index.html index.php /public/index.php;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/chaton-poulpe-pieuvre.tk/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/chaton-poulpe-pieuvre.tk/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/chaton-poulpe-pieuvre.tk/chain.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EECDH+AES;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 80.67.169.12 80.67.169.40 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 5s;

         location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
           }

        autoindex on;

}
```

Thanks for any help guys..

Comment: Eh? I see: "Service temporairement indisponible ou en maintenance"

Answer (score 0):

Try `index index.html index.php /_h5ai/public/index.php;`

Comment: No It wasn't that, I reinstalled my whole server and then it's ok, thanks anyway ^^